# Remove all permission from a user in specific database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, user-permissions, privilege

I have installed MySQL on my local server. I want to create a user with all privilege to all database except one. In this case he also can create a new database and can access it with full functionality.

In another word, how can we remove permission from an specific database. I tried several way, but I was unsuccessful.

I got several situation while giving/revoking permission:

**1:** Revoked select, create, etc from user. It causes to not create a new database or table, etc.

**2:** Given database specific permission to all database except one, and given global permission for create. It causes restriction to perform any task on newly created database by him.

References I used: http://www.lowendtalk.com/discussion/34667/how-to-grant-a-user-to-create-database-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

ok now i got you..

- are you aware of the database-specific privileges?
- click on your existing database and look for a field "Privileges"
- now here you can set privilages for listed users.

[check out this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JzN4.png)